# VS 2017 remote debugging: Illegal instruction when writing to stdout

Tags: c++, linux, cross-platform, visual-studio-2017, remote-debugging

I have the following problem: I am using Visual Studio 2017's cross platform capabilities to devolp a program for my Beagle Bone Black.

Look at the following demo program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    int c = a + b;
    float d = (float)c;
    printf("Hello World!");
    return 0;

}
```

The program compiles without errors and I can execute it remotely from within Visual Studio. I can see the "Hello World!" output on the VS Linux Console (Debug->Linux Console) and everything is working fine.

However, if I set a breakpoint somewhere and step through the program (which works: I can see the values of the variables in VS) the program crashes at the `printf` line and gives an "Illegal instruction" exception/error without more information. The text "Hello world!" is not printed to the console in this case.

Can you tell me what causes the error here and how I can prevent it?
Thanks for any insights!

Comment: This may not fix but you should add `#include <cstdio>`

Comment: There are various issues in VCLinux when debugging a console application in gdbserver mode, see https://github.com/Microsoft/VSLinux/issues/119 for example. Try changing the debugging mode to 'gdb' but note that gdb mode doesn't support console input.

Comment: OK, I guess I just will have to wait until the issues are fixed then! Thanks for the input!

Comment: This has been an issue since the summer of 2016. It's been a year since first discovered so I am unsure if Microsoft will work in it. This is why my group uses VisualGDB instead.